# Vue add suffix to model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try add suffix (date.now) to my model each time when user enter some information in `v-model=Name` to achieve it i try to make it by function `loanDate` which trigger each time when i enter name.

But the problem is is that do not work correctly and i wonder what is the right way to achieve it:

Input field:

```
  <v-text-field
         v-model="Name"
         label="Please enter the Loan Number"
         required
         :rules="nameRules"
          outlined
          @input="loanDate"
    />
```

loanDate function

```
 loanDate() {
      let d = new Date();
      let curr_date = d.getDate();
      let curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
      let curr_year = d.getFullYear();
      let date_ = `${curr_month}${curr_date}${curr_year}`
      this.Name  = this.Name + '.' +  date_
      return this.Name

    },
```

expected result:

```
input => Name => (v-model = Name.03/05/2021)
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `input` event fires on all changes in the text field, so every character gets a date appended to it.

One solution is to switch from the `input` event to the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event), which fires for changes only after the input loses focus:

```html
<v-text-field @change="loanDate" />
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/qBRevMb?editors=1010)